# Android 11 can't read non media file from local storage

Tags: android, android-file, android-11

I faced a problem with file picker in Android 11. File like image or video are readeble, but docs and so on are not.
I double checked storage read permission.

**Example**:

```
uri = content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/103 
someFile = /storage/emulated/0/Download/IMG_20210310_232019_1.jpg
someFile.canRead -> true
```

**But**:

```
uri = content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf:1390 
someFile = /storage/emulated/0/Download/file-example_PDF_1MB.pdf
someFile.canRead() -> false
```

And then:

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to calculate MD5 hash: /storage/emulated/0/Download/file-example_PDF_1MB.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Here is my `FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS`

```
<paths>
    <cache-path
        name="camera"
        path="camera/" />
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <root-path
        name="external_sd_files"
        path="/storage/" />
</paths>
```

File pick function:

```
fun pickFile(fragment: Fragment) {
    val intent = Intent()
    val mimeTypes = arrayOf(
        "image/*",
        "application/msword",
        "text/*",
        "application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument",
        "application/vnd.ms-works",
        "application/xhtml+xml",
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",  // .doc & .docx
        "application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12",  // .dotm
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template",  // .dotx
        "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",  // .ppt & .pptx
        "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",  // .xls & .xlsx
        "application/pdf"
    )
    intent.type = "*/*"
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes)
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true)
    fragment.startActivityForResult(
        intent,
        SELECT_FILE_REQUEST
    )
}
```

onActivityResult:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == ChatFileUtils.SELECT_FILE_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                pickiT.getPath(data.data, Build.VERSION.SDK_INT)
            }
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

Comment: You do not need any permission for uries obtained by ACTION_GET_CONTENT. Further: what are those entry.key stuff? Further: we do not see you read a file. Further: what has a FileProvider to do with this?

Comment: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` You can remove that as it makes no sense.

Comment: "I faced a problem with file picker in Android 11" -- your two examples seem to be unrelated to your `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` request. On modern Android devices, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` will return a `content` `Uri`, not a filesystem path. And, since the content does not have to reside on the device (let alone in a file that you can access), you cannot convert a `content` `Uri` into a filesystem path.

Comment: @CommonsWare I uses HBiSoft/PickiT lib to get actual path to file, wich I use then to get file.

Comment: "I uses HBiSoft/PickiT lib to get actual path to file" -- that has never been a reliable solution, less so on up-to-date versions of Android. I strongly recommend removing that library and using the `Uri` itself (e.g., with `openInputStream()` on `ContentResolver`).